# Como puedo ordenar de forma aleatoria unos documentos de firebase Firestore? (SwiftUI, iOS)

Tags: firebase, swift

Hola alguien me podria ayudar a encontrar una forma sencilla de ordenar los documentos de una colección de forma aleatoria. Esta es la función que utilizo para obtener los documentos, ¿cómo puedo ordenarlos al azar?

```
    func fetchExplore() {
    let query = COLLECTION_POSTS.limit(to: 6)
    
    if let last = lastDoc {
        let next = query.start(afterDocument: last)
        next.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents, !documents.isEmpty else { return }
            self.lastDoc = snapshot?.documents.last
            self.posts.append(contentsOf: documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) }))
        }
    } else {
        query.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
            self.posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
            self.lastDoc = snapshot?.documents.last
        }
    }
    print("DEBUG: did fetch posts Explore")
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En Swift existe la función `shuffle()` que te permite ordenar de manera aleatoria un array.

Para el ejemplo suponiendo que tienes los documentos en un array :

```
var documentos = ["Doc 1", "Doc 2", "Doc 3", "Doc 4"]
//Llamas a la función shuffle()
documentos.shuffle()
print(array)
```

Esto imprime:

```
["Doc 4", "Doc 1", "Doc 3", "Doc 2"]
```

Si ejecutas de nuevo:

```
["Doc 2", "Doc 4", "Doc 1", "Doc 3"]
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la ayuda pero una pregunta... Como puedo implementar eso en mi código?

Comment: Cómo tienes la variable que almacena documentos? Puedes agregar un print y colocar en la pregunta la estructura? Es un array?

Comment: Los documentos están almacenados en una colección de firebase Firestore. Lo que necesito es que los documentos de la colección se ordenen de forma aleatoria. Sabe cómo puedo hacer eso?